# WP-options to stop scripts: here Google-Maps API: wp_dequeue or wp_deregister script? or ... even remove?

Tags: php, wordpress

How to use wp_dequeue to keep a script from loading in WordPress: ...or are there more options here, we can use.

**background:**

first of all: we are talking about this site: https://www.job-starter.com
this site runs: wordpress 6.3.1
plugins: wp-job-manager
theme: jobify-theme by astoundify.com - see https://astoundify.com/products/jobify/

**note:** this theme uses Google-Maps - i do not want to run this on my site - since i do not want to run into legal issues due to the API-calls:

the devs (of the theme) said - the Google_Map_API cally on my site are the following:

```
js?v=3&libraries=geometry%2Cplaces&language=en&ver=6.3. 
common.js 
util.js
```

The theme author is loading the Google Maps API but it isn't being used on the site so I want to dequeue it in the child theme's functions.php. They don't offer an option to simply disable it within the theme settings.
**Question:** Would someone mind helping me out with some ideas about the options we have here:

- a. we could comment it out in the  parents theme or
- b. dequeue it in the child theme? and what about the options to
- c. deregister it, or even more..Just to
- d. remove it

so there are lots of options here: the wp_dequeue code

**questions:**

isnt it technically more efficient to comment it out in the parent theme or dequeue it in the child theme? I know the inherent problems with modifying the parent theme code.
regarding the option ...

we could work with the

```
('bazien-google-maps', 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?kewp_enqueue_script('bazien-google-maps', 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?ke
```

**but wait:**  isnt it the best WordPress way, we 'll need to deregister it in the child theme. to do so, use the following:

```
wp_deregister_script( 'bazien-google-maps' );
```

**conclusio**: it's more efficient to comment it in the parent theme, because this way we don't load the script to "unload" it after. But, an update might appear somedays, so it's more secure to disable it in the child theme.

i am not sure if the above ideas and musings are correct. what do you say...?

*btw:*

> options to stop scripts: here Google-Maps API: wp_dequeue or wp deregister script

right!

btw: if we choose the options 2

**b. dequeue it in the child theme**

that said - the Google_Map_API cally on my site are the following

```
js?v=3&libraries=geometry%2Cplaces&language=en&ver=6.3.
common.js 
util.js
```

​

thus the code in functions.php could be like so

​

```
function dequeue_google_maps_scripts() {
wp_dequeue_script('common.js');
wp_dequeue_script('util.js');
wp_dequeue_script('js?v=3&libraries=geometry%2Cplaces&language=en&ver=6.3.2');

} add\_action('wp\_enqueue\_scripts', 'dequeue\_google\_maps\_scripts', 100);
```

but this does not work; i still have Google-Map-API calls on the page.
what do you say bout this solution..!?

**update:**

have aplied the code - and tried to load the site with a tool that shows the details - but yes: probbly i have to erase the cookies - first.. see the outcome

[image]

Comment: Modifying parent theme code directly, will endanger your ability to update that theme - resp. you would _lose_ your modifications, every time you do. That is one of the main reasons for using child templates in WP in the first place - so that you can override specific parts of your parent theme only, but without getting into too much trouble with updates.

Comment: dear CBroe first of all; many many thanks for the answer and all the hints. Completely agreed: i still struggle with the issues on the page: https://www.job-starters.com - see the google-map-api-calls that i canot get rid of: https://sicher3.de/webscanner/r/c1bd8866-ccde-4016-a7e1-0d15c5b733d6/ - any idea!? i would greatly apprediate any and all help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the theme you're working with is a "premium theme" and I can't buy it just to debug it, I can't exactly reproduce your problem on my end, but after couple of years working with these scenarios, and having to make these decisions myself and seeing results first hand, I would choose option "b", if I were you!

Options:

> a. Feasible but NOT recommended (due to all of the reasons you mentioned in your question)
> **b. This would be my best bet!**
> c. Viable but NOT necessary if you choose "b"
> d. Also viable but NOT necessary if you choose "b"

---

> *"but this does not work"*

**Did you get any error(s)/warning(s)? Did you take a look at your log files?**

**Note:**

In order to use [`wp_dequeue_script`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_dequeue_script/) properly:

- Make sure you pass the scripts **"handles"** to `wp_dequeue_script` function, otherwise it won't work. The **"handle"** may or may not be different than a script name. You would need to look at the source code in order to check whether "handle" is the same as name of a script. Easiest way for you to find out the **"handle"** is to look at the page source on your browser. (right click any where on the page after it's been fully loaded, then click "view page source". On the page source search for your scripts and get the **"handle"**. It's the first section of those scripts)
- Since I don't have access to the source code of your "premium theme" and can't read the source code to see the priority of those scripts being enqueued, therefore, I would suggest to give your  function a low priority (high number) in order to make sure it would run last (Yes I've seen developers use priority higher than 100 depending on the structure of their code).
- Also you don't need to escape your action hook with backslashes in the `function.php` file of your child theme!
- I've also seen `wp_dequeue_script` not working first time you run it due to "browser caching"! So if you did everything correctly and ran it and saw it doesn't work, then make sure to clear your browser cache either by "hard reloading" your page or use your browser `developer tools > network tab`.

For example:

```php
add_action( "wp_enqueue_scripts", "your_theme_dequeue_function", 999 );  

function your_theme_dequeue_function() 
{
    wp_dequeue_script( "REPLACE_THIS_WITH_HANDLE_OF_SCRIPT_1" );
    wp_dequeue_script( "REPLACE_THIS_WITH_HANDLE_OF_SCRIPT_2" );
    wp_dequeue_script( "REPLACE_THIS_WITH_HANDLE_OF_SCRIPT_3" );
}
```

Since your theme is a "premium theme" I am not able to reproduce your problem on my end, so that was all I could think of at this point. Let me know if you could get it to work!

---

#### UPDATE

The source code of the theme you sent me, needed me to login to a third party website in order to get the theme activated. I didn't have account on that third party website nor did I have time to go through that process!

BUT, I took a pretty quick peek into the source code and found several scripts **"handles"** responsible for enqueuing "google maps" api. Here's the code I would suggest to use inside the `functions.php` file of your child theme.

```php
add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts", "your_theme_dequeue_function", 999);

function your_theme_dequeue_function()
{
  wp_dequeue_script("gjm-map");
  wp_dequeue_script("gjm-google-maps");
  wp_dequeue_script("google-maps");
  wp_dequeue_script("jobify-app-map");
  wp_dequeue_script("gjm-info-bubble");
  wp_dequeue_script("gjm-marker-clusterer");
  wp_dequeue_script("gjm-marker-spiderfier");
}
```

It should work, theoretically, and dequeue all of those scripts on your pages, but I wasn't able to test it because of the activation process of this specific theme.

Comment: hi there - dear Ruvee - many thanks for your reply. I am so thankful that you help here. At the moment i did not apply your patch here.  But i will do this in the aftrnoon. Sure thing! btw:  if i have an adress - i am willing to send you the theme.  no problem here. 
look forward to hear from you  - regards

btw: ruvee - i am also extremely grateful to be part of this open source community where people are graciously willing to offer their time and expertise to others: This is so awesome. And i cant say how happy you make me;)

Comment: b. This would be my best bet! - well Ruvee - i agree with you. The b is a truely good chouice. Your answer is very good - and encouraging!! Thank you

Comment: these ideas were very interesting

Comment: dear Ruvee - i am so glad that you provide an answer - btw:  i would love to give you a link to the newest version of the theme. I would love to see you testing it on the newest version of the theme?! - can i provide you with the link to a download!? that would be awesome!! look forward to hear from you ...

Comment: **btw:** dear @Ruvee: I have attached the theme file in a  Google Drive link see the bottom of the inital posting: i will leave this link there - untill i hear from you again - and i can erase  the link afterwards. Many thanks for all you do.

Comment: hi dear Ruvee -  many many thanks this is absolute awesome. You made my day. And i am soooo glad.... ;)

Comment: @thannen I just updated my answer. Give it a shot and let me know if you could get it to work!

Comment: hi there - many many thanks - i will test it later the day. Many thanks for the awesome work. I will test it and come back to you. regards

Comment: hi there 
**update:** 

have aplied the code - and tried to load the site with a tool that shows the details - but yes: probbly i have to erase the cookies - first.. see the outcome at the end of the orignal posting ... the image. 
but yes - probably i have to erase the cookies first... to do a valid check - what do you  say!?